# Generate a file on the fly and save it to S3 with Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

When a user registers I need to generate a file and immediately send it to an S3 bucket. How can I do this without using something like paperclip or any other similar gem? I want to avoid these gems because there is nothing being uploaded by any users; the app itself is generating the file for each user.

Comment: Perhaps something like this will help? https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3

Comment: That looks like a winner. Maybe you should submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use a the ruby [aws-s3 gem](https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3) to interact w/ S3 from your application.

There is also [fog](https://github.com/fog/fog) which is more of a general cloud interaction library (e.g. supports many different cloud services), but I think it is overkill for this need.